# What is the command to run protractor tests in saucelabs

Tags: selenium, protractor, saucelabs

I am trying to run my protractor tests in saucelabs and cannot figure out what commands to use to run the tests.  I have my `sauceUser` and `sauceKey` in the conf.js.

This is the command I usually use to run the test locally

`export TEST_ENV='dev'; ./node_modules/.bin/protractor e2e/conf.js`

```
exports.config = {
    sauceUser: '<user>',
    sauceKey: '<key>',
    directConnect: true,
    framework: 'mocha',
    onComplete: function () {

    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        // Declaring chai here so it can be accessed through out the tests and
        // there is no need to declare it in every test.
        var chai = require('chai');
        chai.use(require('chai-smoothie'));
        var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
        var chaiSmoothie = require('chai-smoothie')
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        chai.use(chaiSmoothie);
        var expect = chai.expect;
        global.chai = chai;
        browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    },
    mochaOpts: {
        timeout: 30000,
        reporter: 'mochawesome-screenshots',
        reporterOptions: {
            reportDir: 'e2e/reports', //The directory which stores the reports
            reportName: 'TestExecutionReport',
            reportTitle: 'Reports',
            reportPageTitle: 'customReportPageTitle',
            clearOldScreenshots: false,
            jsonReport: false,
            multiReport: true,
            overwrite: true
        }
    },

        specs: [
         'test-spec.js'
    ],
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'shardTestFiles': true,
        'maxInstances': 1,
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['show-fps-counter=true', 'incognito', '--window-size=1200,800', 'use-fake-ui-for-media-stream']
        }
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 12000,
    getPageTimeout: 12000,
};
```

Comment: Please include your conf.js, so we can disect further. The common mistake is that you still included the **seleniumAddress:** field in your conf.js.

Comment: @GoLGo13 - I've added my conf.js

Comment: @GoLGo13 - if I run the same command, should it automatically start running it on saucelabs?

Comment: Remove `directConnect: true` and see if it helps

Comment: That worked.  Thank you